# Obtain a value of an Indicator at the open in Pinescript

Tags: pine-script, pine-script-v5

I would like to obtain the value of an indicator (say a simple moving average), but I want the indicator's value at the bar's open. I would then plot this value.

I have tried using the time function, but can't make it work.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

In pinescript all calculation are maid at the bar close (which is the bar open of the next bar).
If you want to draw the value of your indicator at the bar's open, just use the [1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/B8zX9.png) index on your indicator to plot  :
it will plot on your bar the value of the close of the preceding bar = value of the open of your bar.
for example :

```
//@version=5
indicator("My script", overlay=true)
MyIndicator = ta.sma(close, 20)
plot(MyIndicator, color=color.green)
plot( MyIndicator[1], color=color.red)
```

This will give you this :
[image]